# How do I interpret this declaration that appears to be a function declaration, but doesn't fit the usual mould?

Tags: c, function, declaration, function-declaration

I'm trying to decipher this declaration from sqlite3.c

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE void (*sqlite3OsDlSym(sqlite3_vfs *, void *, const char *))(void);
```

It seems like it is declaring a function because subsequently there is this

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE void (*sqlite3OsDlSym(sqlite3_vfs *pVfs, void *pHdle, const char *zSym))(void){
  return pVfs->xDlSym(pVfs, pHdle, zSym);
}
```

and then what appear to be calls to the function

```
xInit = (sqlite3_loadext_entry)sqlite3OsDlSym(pVfs, handle, zEntry);
```

and

```
xInit = (sqlite3_loadext_entry)sqlite3OsDlSym(pVfs, handle, zEntry);
```

But I cannot make sense of the declaration. I've highlighted what I cannot understand

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE void (*sqlite3OsDlSym(sqlite3_vfs *, void *, const char *))(void);
                    ^                                                    ^^^^^^^
```

I'm wondering why the declaration is not like so

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE void *sqlite3OsDlSym(sqlite3_vfs *, void *, const char *);
```

I expect that there may well be a similar question already asked but searching for terms like `(`, `)` and `void` doesn't really get anywhere. So, if this is a dupe, I'd be very happy for it to be closed as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is declaring a function that returns a function pointer. The return type is `void (*)(void)` (`SQLITE_PRIVATE` expands to `static` and is not part of the return type, per comments), but the function name (and parameters) have to appear inside the `(*)` part.

Functions and arrays are the two C type categories that require to do gymnastics to parse. You can think of array types and function types as "decorating" the identifier that they describe. If you write `int foo`, you're saying that the symbol "foo" has an integer type. If you write `int foo(double)`, you're saying that the symbol `foo(double)` has an integer type. `foo` and `(double)` have to stick together, so any further decoration has to wrap the entire thing as if it was a single name.

The point is best illustrated by mixing array types and function types, even though the end type might not be legal in C. (That says a lot about how ridiculous the syntax is.) For instance:

```
int foo[5](double)
```

would be an array (`foo[5]`) of functions (`int ... (double)`). On the other hand:

```
int foo(double)[5]
```

is a function (`foo(double)`) and returns an array (`int ... [5]`).

The external resource [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*sqlite3OsDlSym%28void+*%2C+void+*%2C+const+char+*%29%29%28void%29%3B) can help you make sense of this kind of declaration. However, you need to replace the structure names with standard types (or write structure types as `struct sqlite_vfs` instead of just `sqlite_vfs`) for it to understand your declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I tried cdecl.org, but couldn't get it to give me anything other than "syntax error". I can see now that was because it did not recognise `sqlite3_vfs`. If I'd just replaced `sqlite3_vfs` with `int` then I would have had my answer.

Comment: And the other thing that caught me out I suppose is that although `sqlite3OsDlSym` returns "pointer to function (void) returning void", the actual function pointer returned has different prototype, hence the `(sqlite3_loadext_entry)` cast.

Comment: Depending on what `SQLITE_PRIVATE` actually is, it may apply to the function being declared rather than the return type  (e.g. if it were a macro for `static`)

Comment: `SQLITE_PRIVATE` expands to `static` I believe

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE void (*sqlite3OsDlSym(sqlite3_vfs *, void *, const char *))(void);
```

is a declaration of a function that has the return type that is function pointer of the type

```
void ( * )( void )
```

The declaration can be simplified by introducing a typedef. For example

```
typedef void ( *FP )( void );

SQLITE_PRIVATE  FP sqlite3OsDlSym(sqlite3_vfs *, void *, const char *);
```

Here is a demonstrative program that uses a similar function that returns a pointer to another function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void ( *FP )( void );

void h( void )
{
    puts( "Hello World" );
}

FP f( void );
void ( *f( void) )( void )
{
    return h;
}

int main(void) 
{
    f()();

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello World
```

At first the function `f` is declared using a typedef and then without the typedef

```
FP f( void );
void ( *f( void) )( void )
{
    return h;
}
```